# How to filter queryset based on boolean value, then count in template

Tags: python, django

I want to count how many jobs are open vs closed.  I don't understand why this isn't working, I have added {{ap.id}} and {{open.line_num_id }} after the forloop just to see what was rendered.  I would think that if they match, then it's added to the count. This is not the case, all jobs are counted regardless of the "if" statement. Totally lost as to what is happening and why.  Any help would be very appreciated .

I have two models:

```
class Airplane(models.Model):
    line_num = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    vh_num = models.CharField(max_length=4, unique=True)
    vz_num = models.CharField(max_length=4, unique=True)
    stall = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=stall_picker)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=status_picker)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    pm = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.line_num

class Job(models.Model):
    line_num = models.ForeignKey(
        Airplane, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="ap_jobs")
    job_num = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=status_picker)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=categories_picker)
    is_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class meta:
        ordering = ["category", "status"]

    def __str__(self):
        return (f"{self.job_num}: {self.description} : {self.is_completed}")
```

My View:

```
def Ap_linup(request):
    context = {
        'ap_list': Airplane.objects.all().filter(is_completed=False),
        'open_jobs': Job.objects.all().filter(is_completed=False),
        'closed_jobs': Job.objects.all().filter(is_completed=True)
    }
    
    return render(request, 'airplane/airplane_list.html', context)
```

Template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %} Airplane List {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<center>
    <div class="row">
        {% for ap in ap_list %}
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h1>
                        <center>
                            <a href="{% url 'airplane:ap_detail' ap.id %}">{{ ap.line_num }}</a>
                        </center>
                    </h1>
                    <h3>
                        <p>Stall:<strong>{{ ap.stall }}</strong> VH:<strong>{{ ap.vh_num }}</strong> VZ:<strong>{{ap.vz_num }}</strong>
                        <p>MGR: {{ ap.owner }}</p>
                        <hr class="lead border border-dark">
                        <h1>{{ ap.id }}</h1>
                        {% if ap.status == "Avalible" %}
                        <p>Current Status:</p>
                        <p class="text-success">{{ ap.status }}</p>
                        {% else %}
                        <p>Current Status:</p>
                        <p class="text-danger">{{ ap.status }}</p>
                        {% endif %}
                    </h3>  
                    <!-- Open Job counts -->
                    <div> 
                        {% for open in open_jobs %}
                        {% if open.line_num_id == ap.id %}</p>
                            <p>Open Jobs: {{ open_jobs.count }}</p>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                        {% for closed in closed_jobs %}
                        {% if closed.line_num_id == ap.id %}</p>
                            <p>Closed Jobs: {{ closed_jobs.count }}</p>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="lead border border-dark">
                        {% for comment in ap.ap_comments.all %}
                            {% if comment_id == ap_id %}
                                    <p><strong>{{ comment.author }}</strong>: {{ comment.text }} @ {{comment.created_at }}</p>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        
    </div>
</center>



{% endblock %}
```

OUTPUT:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baBgV.png)

I want to display open and closed job counts per Airplane.  Count of Open and Close jobs just add up to total jobs on Airplane.

Comment: Don't count in the template: Django's template language is deliberately restricted to discourage people to do that. You should write such logic in the view.

Comment: Job.objects.filter(is_completed=False).count() it will be counted in database

Comment: @KuskoAndrew:  Ok, if my database has 3 open jobs, 2 on AP1 and the other on AP2, wouldn't the "if" statement determine which AP the jobs belong to?  if not please help me to understand how to go about this correctly.

{% If open_jobs.line_num_id ==ap.id %)

AP1 open jobs =2
AP2 open jobs =1

Comment: @jesserown yep, mr ja408 wrote nice answer. 
pls mark it as correct if it is)

Comment: @ja408: How do I use this in the template?

Comment: @JesseBrown I've updated my answer with an `UPDATE` at the bottom to explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kusko mentions in the comments, you can pass that number to the context.  You can do so by doing something like this:

```
def Ap_linup(request):
    context = {
        'ap_list': Airplane.objects.all().filter(is_completed=False),
        'open_jobs': Job.objects.all().filter(is_completed=False),
        'closed_jobs': Job.objects.all().filter(is_completed=True),
        'open_jobs_count': Job.objects.filter(is_completed=False).count(),
        'closed_jobs_count': Job.objects.filter(is_completed=True).count()
    }
```

Also, you don't need `.all()` because filter is sufficient.

and if you wanted to clean up the code a bit more so you don't have a lot of queries, you can declare variables before the context.

```
def Ap_linup(request):
    open_jobs = Job.objects.filter(is_completed=False)
    closed_jobs = Job.objects.filter(is_completed=True)

    context = {
        'ap_list': Airplane.objects.all().filter(is_completed=False),
        'open_jobs': open_jobs,
        'closed_jobs': closed_jobs,
        'open_jobs_count': open_jobs.count(),
        'closed_jobs_count': closed_jobs.count()
    }
    
    return render(request, 'airplane/airplane_list.html', context)
```

UPDATE:

To display this information in the template you can do this outside of your loop:

For closed jobs you just call the variable you set in the context

```
<p>Closed Jobs: {{ closed_jobs_count }}</p>
```

and for open jobs you would do the same thing

```
<p>Open Jobs: {{ open_jobs_count }}</p>
```

You no longer need to add a `.count` to the template because you already did the work on the backend.  The value stored in `closed_jobs_count` and `open_jobs_count` is an number.